# Ckeditor disable add auto div and br tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I had install ckeditor working fine, But its adding a lots of line breaks and div tags after every save.

Please advice me how i can handle that. So that it does not adds extra line breaks and div after saving the form

Comment: You should put your code to be reviewed.

Comment: i just want to know how to disable auto add br tags in full package of ckeditor

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719121/ckeditor4-br-tags-are-inserted-inside-empty-p-p-blocks