# CKEditor4 <br> tags are inserted inside empty <p></p> blocks

Tags: ckeditor

I used the following way to render some content into div by using CKEditor4:

```
// the config is my CKEDITOR.config
// this._editorElement is the element in which I will render my CKEditor
const myEditor: CKEDITOR.editor = CKEDITOR.inline(this._editorElement, config);
myEditor.setData("<p></p><div>aaa</div><p></p><div>bbb</div>");
```

However, after the content was rendered into the page, it changed into:
`<p><br></p><div>aaa</div><p><br></p><div>bbb</div>`.

As you can see, `<br>` is inserted into empty `<p></p>` blocks. However, I don't want this to happen. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I am running into this behavior too - what does CKEditor inject a <br> into an empty <div>?